# How can I paginate a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, pagination

How can I set paging in a wpf `DataGrid`?

Comment: Please check this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Paging.aspx) in codeproject

Answer (score 61):

The code project article above is quite good for getting this done with ADO tables. While for most applications, it is likely to work great, and is easy to understand, there is a more "WPF-zen-like" way to do it as well, and that would be using CollectionViews. The advantage of using a CollectionView compared to the example above is that it is a bit more general in terms of what data you're putting in your grid (not that you can't make that example more general), and it fits in well with the general WPF databinding model. It gives you a place to support common operations like sorting, grouping, etc, if you need those.

I put together a very short example of a barely working PagingCollectionView bound to the .NET 4.0 DataGrid control. While the example itself is pretty trivial, it shows you at least how to get started, as you have a proxy around the actual collection of data on which you can execute simple operations like MoveToNextPage and MoveToPreviousPage.

Here's the C# for both the Window event handling and the PagingCollectionView:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace GridPagingExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly PagingCollectionView _cview;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this._cview = new PagingCollectionView(
                new List<object>
                {
                    new { Animal = "Lion", Eats = "Tiger" },
                    new { Animal = "Tiger", Eats =  "Bear" },
                    new { Animal = "Bear", Eats = "Oh my" },
                    new { Animal = "Wait", Eats = "Oh my isn't an animal" },
                    new { Animal = "Oh well", Eats = "Who is counting anyway" },
                    new { Animal = "Need better content", Eats = "For posting on stackoverflow" }
                },
                2
            );
            this.DataContext = this._cview;
        }

        private void OnNextClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._cview.MoveToNextPage();
        }

        private void OnPreviousClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._cview.MoveToPreviousPage();
        }
    }

    public class PagingCollectionView : CollectionView
    {
        private readonly IList _innerList;
        private readonly int _itemsPerPage;

        private int _currentPage = 1;

        public PagingCollectionView(IList innerList, int itemsPerPage)
            : base(innerList)
        {
            this._innerList = innerList;
            this._itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get 
            { 
                if (this._innerList.Count == 0) return 0;
                if (this._currentPage < this.PageCount) // page 1..n-1
                {
                    return this._itemsPerPage;
                }
                else // page n
                {
                    var itemsLeft = this._innerList.Count % this._itemsPerPage;
                    if (0 == itemsLeft)
                    {
                        return this._itemsPerPage; // exactly itemsPerPage left
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // return the remaining items
                        return itemsLeft;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get { return this._currentPage; }
            set
            {
                this._currentPage = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPage"));
            }
        }

        public int ItemsPerPage { get { return this._itemsPerPage; } }

        public int PageCount
        {
            get 
            { 
                return (this._innerList.Count + this._itemsPerPage - 1) 
                    / this._itemsPerPage; 
            }
        }

        private int EndIndex
        {
            get
            {
                var end = this._currentPage * this._itemsPerPage - 1;
                return (end > this._innerList.Count) ? this._innerList.Count : end;
            }
        }

        private int StartIndex
        {
            get { return (this._currentPage - 1) * this._itemsPerPage; }
        }

        public override object GetItemAt(int index)
        {
            var offset = index % (this._itemsPerPage); 
            return this._innerList[this.StartIndex + offset];
        }

        public void MoveToNextPage()
        {
            if (this._currentPage < this.PageCount)
            {
                this.CurrentPage += 1;
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }

        public void MoveToPreviousPage()
        {
            if (this._currentPage > 1)
            {
                this.CurrentPage -= 1;
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the XAML for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="GridPagingExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="2">
                <Label.Content>
                    <Binding Path="CurrentPage">
                        <Binding.StringFormat>Current Page: {0}</Binding.StringFormat>
                    </Binding>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>
            <Button Content="Next" Click="OnNextClicked" Margin="2"/>
            <Button Content="Previous" Click="OnPreviousClicked" Margin="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Animal" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Animal}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Eats" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Eats}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You could build out this CollectionView to support more functionality, some trivial, like MoveToLastPage and MoveToFirstPage, and some that will take some more thought about how you want it to behave, such as sorting. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Also, Silverlight has one of these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(v=vs.95).aspx, so looking at that with Reflector might also be a very helpful example to work off of. Good luck!

Comment: This code seems to miss a crucial part: how to make the datagrid just show ItemsPerPage instead of all items, right?

Comment: The silverlight one works and has the advantage that it is editable. I've posted more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25392986/385995

Comment: It seems to not support the built-in Filter property of the CollectionView that it derives - it appears to ignore it.

Comment: You get a massive performance boost (and presumably fewer bugs) if you replace the base class with ListCollectionView - regular CollectionViews use lots of deprecated behavior and are not meant to be instantiated as-is anymore (see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Data/CollectionView.cs).

Comment: In order to fix the lack of filtering functionality you must override RefreshOverride() and perform the filtering there to affect _innerList - I recommend using the ListCollectionView source's content for that function as a guide for that. It was caused by using our own list rather than the in-built CollectionView one that we can't access.

Comment: i have used it and it works great. however i also suffered from the out of range problem before, and somehow i resolved it from a solution i found somewhere. but i noticed that it disables the default sorting functionality of datagrid. How do i resolve it? @timmyl

Comment: @wingskush - this example doesn't support sorting. I'd suggest using the Microsoft implementation from the Silverlight dll's as it is a more complete implementation that supports sorting, filtering and doesn't suffer from a bunch of random bugs.

Comment: this should be a control in WPF by default :-) good work, i did some tinkering with it tho, but just layout and a tad of code.

Comment: @Yushatak, could you post how to override Refresh() method ? I can't enable filtering too.

Comment: @Yushatak @Lucy82 Re-implementing filtering manually really defeats the purpose of inheriting from a `CollectionView` in the first place. There is no way of making both filtering, sorting, and grouping functionality work with this example. When you are done re-implementing all of the functionalities you don't need the base class anymore.
You just have to start from scratch and implement the `ICollectionView`, without inheriting from any of the `CollectionView` classes. If you notice, that's what the Silverlight class did as well.