# Paged Collection View in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, paging, collectionview

Is there an implementation of PagedCollectionView in WPF around? It exists in Silverlight but isn't in WPF.

If there isn't, what would be the simplest way to implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply take the code from the [Silverlight one](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70993#780506) and use that in your WPF project.

Comment: Sorry I know this is really old but I feel I'm missing something here, there seems to be a whole bunch of dependencies which would also need porting?

Comment: It's been a long time. I believe there are some dependencies, but they're all very localised and easy to copy across.

Comment: Thanks Kent, I found this link which contained everything required : 
https://silverlight.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Release/Silverlight4/Source/System.Windows.Data/PagedCollectionView/ for anyone else finding this.

Comment: Do you need to download the source code or can you import the apparently native `DataPager` control? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/dd538632(v%3Dvs.95)

Answer (score 1):

Or use only the CollectionView class and "double filter" your collection

solution found here: [Own CollectionView for paging, sorting and filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823349/own-collectionview-for-paging-sorting-and-filtering/43549392#43549392)

I've pasted the code snipet here for your convinience:

```
        // obtenir la CollectionView 
        ICollectionView cvCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Suivis);
        if (cvCollectionView == null)
            return;

        // filtrer ... exemple pour tests DI-2015-05105-0
        cvCollectionView.Filter = p_oObject => { return true; /* use your own filter */ };

        // page configuration
        int iMaxItemPerPage = 2;
        int iCurrentPage = 0;
        int iStartIndex = iCurrentPage * iMaxItemPerPage;

        // déterminer les objects "de la page"
        int iCurrentIndex = 0;
        HashSet<object> hsObjectsInPage = new HashSet<object>();
        foreach (object oObject in cvCollectionView)
        {
            // break if MaxItemCount is reached
            if (hsObjectsInPage.Count > iMaxItemPerPage)
                break;

            // add if StartIndex is reached
            if (iCurrentIndex >= iStartIndex)
                hsObjectsInPage.Add(oObject);

            // increment
            iCurrentIndex++;
        }

        // refilter
        cvCollectionView.Filter = p_oObject =>
        {
            return hsObjectsInPage.Contains(p_oObject);
        };
```

Comment: @Edward For the same reason you bothered to comment on it?

Comment: Using `IndexOf` on a collection view itself is complicated, but I& you can access that method, your filter predicate can just be `Math.Floor(collectionView.IndexOf(item) / iMaxItemPerPage) == iCurrentPage`. I haven’t tested this in my own implementation but I’m pretty sure it works!

Comment: @JonathanTuzman, where must above solution actually be implemented? And how ?

Comment: @Lucy82 I think it would be where the code above says “use your own filter”