# Good example of Paging User Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, paging

I searched internet for paging user control code but could not find anyone which satisfy below condition :

Note : I fetched all rows in one service call and store the collection in parent viewmodel (lets say **ObservableCollection objMyList**).

1. All paging logic in PagingControlVM not in xaml.cs file
2. No tightly couple binding between paging control and parent control like I just drop the pagecontrol in parent page and create only one dependency property(lets say MyDepProp) in PagingControl.xaml.cs file  .
3. When PagingControl drop in ParentControl , I use this dependency property to bind with ObservableCollection objMyList
   (I  succeed so far but how I can get the value of dependency property    in PagingControlVM. I want to get the value of MyDepProp in new collection in  PagingControlVM   ).

   If I am doing wrong please tell me good approach.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Im bit confused on your approach.  So.  you want pagination in MVVM.  Is that Right?

Comment: Yes.I want paging control to follow MVVM pattern

Comment: @Verma , I have updated my answer.  Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need of `PagingControlVM` here.  What you need is to have a own `class` inherited from `CollectionView` (say `PagingCollectionView`) where all your paging logics should be there.  Then, you have to create an instance of `PagingCollectionView` as `objMyList`  in your parent viewmodel that can be passed to the `UserControl`'s `ItemsSource`.

For more info:  [Own CollectionView for paging, sorting and filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823349/own-collectionview-for-paging-sorting-and-filtering)

**Edit based on your comment:**

If you want to change the list, changes will be notified as we have implemented the `PagingCollectionView` from `CollectionView`.

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _objMyList ;

    public ObservableCollection<string> objMyList 
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set { _list = value; }
    }

    private PagingCollectionView _pagingsource;      

    public PagingCollectionView PagingSource
    {
        get
        {
            if(_pagingsource == null)
                _pagingsource = new PagingCollectionView(List, 5);                
            return _pagingsource;
        }
    }
```

Bind the `PagingSource` to the UI.  You can always change the `objMyList` that will be notified to UI.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Purpose of UserControl is just drop it in parent  xaml and use it. According to your comment (you have to create an instance of PagingCollectionView as objMyList in your parent viewmodel) I need to modify my Parent VM which is wrong.

Comment: @A.Verma Yes, you can modify the ParenVM that will be reflected since `PagingCollectionView` is from `CollectionView` changes will be notified as `ObservableCollection` do.

Comment: @A.Verma See my updated answer on how to change the list.

Comment: I was thinking just to use Paging User Control without modifying  Parent ViewModel but accr to your comment I will have to wrote below code in my  parent view model , right  ??

 public PagingCollectionView PagingSource
    {
        get
        {
            if(_pagingsource == null)
                _pagingsource = new PagingCollectionView(List, 5);                
            return _pagingsource;
        }
    }

Comment: @A.Verma Yes.  You are right.  you have to write it in parenVM

Comment: Ok. One more question : Is it possible to get the value of dependency property (written in usercontrol1.xaml.cs ) from usercontrol1VM.cs file ?

Comment: @A.Verma Don't know why you need `usercontrol1VM.cs` here.  I think you need to have better understanding on MVVM.  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35395128/2819451)

Comment: Ok...Even I was also thinking in same way (writing all logic in code behind file) but then I realized it will violate MVVM pattern.But after reading above post that you shared it will not violate MVVM rules. Thanks for sharing...