# Is there automatic paging in Wpf

Tags: wpf

On Microsoft official site i read this:

> The GridView control also has a number of new features and advantages over the DataGrid control, which include: 
>   -Richer design-time capabilities. 
>   -Improved data source binding capabilities. 
>   -Automatic handling of sorting, paging, updates, and deletes. ...

So my question is :  Is there automatic paging whatsoever in WPF ?

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean of  `paging`? Show specified number of lines data one time? Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003845

Comment: I am afraid your quote is talking about **ASP.NET** controls, not about WPF ones...