# Datagrid loading large amount of data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am currently using a WPF datagrid which needs to be able to load a large amount of data around 500k of rows fast, as at present it is very slow..

This is of course going to slow the datagrid down as the data is so large. What is the best way to load this data, I only want to really load what the user will actually be viewing but am really unsure how to do this, any help and examples would be amazing.

I am currently reading in from a csv and populating a datagrid, with this information.

I am using c# and  .net 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up some sort of paging. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974872/466903) describes how to do it with CollectionViews.

Comment: +1 here is my personal proposal: http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/10/11/SomeProgressWithFlyFetch.aspx