# paginate List of dictionaries in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, datagrid, pagination

I am having my list of data in

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>>
```

and i have assingned it to the ienumerable type

```
 public IEnumerable Result;
 Result = Datasource.DataSourceCreator.ToDataSource( System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>>);
```

and i binded that ienumerable to an itemsource of a datagrid in my wpf application. How can i paginate my datagrid by traversing this List of dictionary??
Thanks in advance, if u can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not provide a control with built-in pagination support.
You'll need to implement it by yourself.

This article can help you to achieve such thing:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20463/DataView-Paging-in-WPF

Answer (score 0):

The following link might help you to achieve your goal,

[How can I paginate a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid)

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

One more link for your reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350447/WPF-Paging-in-DataGrid-ListBox