# WPF Paging implement crash when selection is changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid, collectionview

I am using the following code for a wpf `DataGrid`:

[How can I paginate a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid)

The paging works fine except that when i move to any page besides the first one and try to pick (press) any row/cell i am getting the following exception :

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: position

BTW - i needed to change the declare of PagingCollectionView _cview to be not readonly.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="rightGrid" x:Uid="rightGrid" SelectionChanged="rightGrid_SelectionChanged">
...
```

And

```
private void rightGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: you need to specify more info there is no position variable

Comment: there is no position variable in my code either... thats what makes this odd... i think its some kind of a private internal var regarding the datagrid

Comment: try to create a sample, without it seems like nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

The code on the [referenced post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid) was meant as an example of how to get started and has [at least one bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300154/wpf-datagrid-pagination) in it (likely more than one).

As others have suggested in the comments, you might want to look at using the [silverlight implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: As an aside, I'll look at updating that post with the bug fix as this isn't the first person to read the answer and run into this problem.