# WPF DataGrid Pagination

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, pagination

I am using the example provided here [StackOverflow related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid), if i have an even number of items in the grid then it works all good, but if for instance i have an odd number like 7 items, it throws a out of range exception which I fixed by adding this line

```
public override object GetItemAt(int index)
{
    var offset = ((index % (this._itemsPerPage)) + this.StartIndex) > this._innerList.Count - 1 ? 0 : index % (this._itemsPerPage);
    return this._innerList[this.StartIndex + offset];
}
```

The problem is that after fixing this, if you set the items per page to 2 then you will have 4 pages, the first 3 pages look right but the last one repeats the last item twice. like this

[image]

I am new to WPF and i am not sure how i can handle this piece, i do not understand why it would repeat the item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not with `GetItemAt` method, leave it as it was:

```
    public override object GetItemAt(int index)
    {
        var offset = index % (this._itemsPerPage); 

        return this._innerList[this.StartIndex + offset];
    }
```

The problem is with `Count` property override. In case it is the last page it should return the correct items left:

```
    public override int Count
    {
        get 
        {
            //all pages except the last
            if (CurrentPage < PageCount)
                return this._itemsPerPage;

            //last page
            int remainder = _innerList.Count % this._itemsPerPage;

            return remainder == 0 ? this._itemsPerPage : remainder; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also if you want to support an empty dataset, you need a check like this at the beginning of that Count override: "if (_innerList.Count == 0) return 0;"

Comment: well i would like to implement sorting @Yushatak. Somehow default sorting of datagrid doesn't work when the itemsource is  binded to the paging's collectionview.

Comment: Sorting is not working, because the `public override object GetItemAt(int index)` method takes the item from the separately maintained `_internalList`. The base class has the items properly sorted (you can see that during debugging), but the `PagingCollectionView` is not using those items. Unfortunately, the internal list of the base class is not protected, so it's not possible to write a decent child class. I find it odd that WPF doesn't support this out of the box.