# how to implement "nextpage" function for datagrid in wpf mvvmlight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

there is a datagrid binding to StudentsViewModel.  there r many students like 100,i just want to display 10 students on current page, each page 10 students, then i can go to next page or previous page, the StudentsViewModel has a property of Students, i add another proprerty :currentpageStudents ,how to get currentpageStudents from Students? and make goto next page function

```
private ObservableCollection<StudentModel> _Students;
    public ObservableCollection<StudentModel> Studnets
    {
        get
        {
            return _Students;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Students != value)
            {
                _Students = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Students");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very similiar to this one: [How can I paginate a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid)

but instead of putting stuff into code behind, you should put it into viewmodel. Also, instead of using clicked events, you should bind buttons `Command` against your viewmodel property. The magic happens inside `PagingCollectionView`, so you don't need to actually keep two collections in your viewmodel.

The termin you want to know is "pagination".