# DataContext/DataGrid creating duplicate rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, pagination, datacontext

I've been wracking my brain for several hours trying to figure out what's causing this.  I have an Access database that feeds a DataGrid in C#/WPF.  I'm using a DataTable fed into a custom class for Paginating a CollectionView, which feeds into a DataContext that is bound to the DataGrid.  I've traced this all the way from program launch to the drawing of the DataGrid, and the correct number of Rows is present at all times (using MessageBox.Show(CollectionView.Count.ToString()) to verify it).  There are a correct number of items (200) even after the DataGrid is drawn, so I'm thinking it must be something in how the DataGrid displays the items after running them through the Pagination class, but I can't seem to find anyplace the problem could stem from.  Could someone take a look at this code and see if they notice anything that could cause this?

A couple notes on the display of the duplicates:  If I change the itemsPerPage value in the method call, it affects how the duplicates are separated.  If it's 200 per page, there are 8 duplicates in a group.  100 per page results in 4 duplicates of one row followed by 4 another, then 4 of the first again.  So like this:

- 200 itemsPerPage:      aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc dddddddd
- 100 itemsPerPage:      aaaa bbbb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd cccc dddd

Obviously these are rows, so they go down instead of to the left, but the concept should hopefully be clear.

**Update:**  I forgot to mention before, but the Pagination class is based off of an answer to this question: [How can I paginate a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid)

**DataGrid XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="instrumentIdDataGrid" ColumnWidth="Auto" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource datagridCenterHeaderStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource datagridCenterCellStyle}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Padding="10"
                      AutoGeneratingColumn="instrumentIdDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Agent TID" Binding="{Binding AgentTID}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team" Binding="{Binding Team}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instrument ID" Binding="{Binding InstrumentID}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="On-Dialer" Binding="{Binding OnDialerExtension}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Off-Dialer" Binding="{Binding OffDialerExtension}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

**DataTable Loading Methods:**(Only the `instruments` DataGrid uses the pagination right now, the dialerRecords one doesn't and is fine.)

```
private void InitializeDataTables()
    {
        FillDataTable(dialerRecords, @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + backendFilePath + ";User Id=;Password=;", "SELECT * FROM DialerRecords");
        FillDataTable(instruments, @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + backendFilePath + ";User Id=;Password=;", "SELECT * FROM InstrumentIDs");

        this.instrumentCollectionView = new PagingCollectionView(instruments.DefaultView, 20);

        instrumentIdDataGrid.DataContext = instrumentCollectionView;
        dialerRecordsDataGrid.DataContext = dialerRecords.DefaultView;
    }

private void FillDataTable(System.Data.DataTable table, string connectionString, string queryString)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection))
            {
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Pagination Class**

```
public class PagingCollectionView : ListCollectionView
{
    private readonly IList _innerList;
    private readonly int _itemsPerPage;

    private int _currentPage = 1;

    public PagingCollectionView(IList innerList, int itemsPerPage) : base(innerList)
    {
        this._innerList = innerList;
        this._itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._innerList.Count == 0)
                return 0;
            if(this._currentPage < this.PageCount)
            {
                return this._itemsPerPage;
            }
            else
            {
                int itemsLeft = this._innerList.Count % this._itemsPerPage;
                if (0 == itemsLeft)
                {
                    return this._itemsPerPage;
                }
                else
                {
                    return itemsLeft;
                }
            }                
        }
    }

    public int CurrentPage
    {
        get { return this._currentPage; }
        set
        {
            this._currentPage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPage"));
        }
    }

    public int ItemsPerPage
    {
        get
        {
            return this._itemsPerPage;
        }
    }

    public int PageCount
    {
        get
        {
            int end = this._currentPage * this._itemsPerPage - 1;
            return (end > this._innerList.Count) ? this._innerList.Count : end;
        }
    }

    private int StartIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return (this._currentPage - 1) * this._itemsPerPage;
        }
    }

    public override object GetItemAt(int index)
    {
        int offset = index & (this._itemsPerPage);
        return this._innerList[this.StartIndex + offset];
    }

    public void MoveToNextPage()
    {
        if (this._currentPage < this.PageCount)
        {
            this.CurrentPage += 1;
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }

    public void MoveToPreviousPage()
    {
        if(this._currentPage > 1)
        {
            this.CurrentPage -= 1;
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this first just to see what happens.  Get rid of this markup AutoGeneratingColumn="instrumentIdDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"

Comment: Removing the markup resulted in the same issue, no change.  I did suspect this might be the issue, hence the reason I had changed `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` whereas before it was true.  I wasn't positive at the time, but I thought changing to `False` would prevent the Event from triggering.  Definitely nice to know that is the case though, and I still appreciate the suggestion!  :)

Comment: Ok, try this, get rid of the paging and bind directly to the content of the instrument collection view.

Comment: That's actually what I had initially, before adding the Paging class (I thought I had put that in the original question but must have forgotten to).  Before the paging class, it worked perfectly, with no duplications.  The only reason for adding the paging class was because the load times when bringing the DataGrid into focus was extreme, somewhere around 90-120 seconds.  I tried several ways to cut this down, but nothing worked, so I searched for and found the paging class.  I'm sure based off this that the problem must be in the paging class, but I can't figure out what could be causing it.

Comment: Ok, so I just found the problem.  I went back and double-checked against the original question's code, and found that I mixed two methods in the Paging class and mistyped an operator in another method.  Basically I merged the `EndIndex` & `PageCount` methods.  Thank you for your help anyways, I really appreciate it, it got me to look back at the code and compare, thus finding the issue. :)

Comment: @KevenM Make sure to add that as an answer so that others with the same or similar problem might benefit from your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the problem was a simple case of mistyping.  As I updated the question to reflect, I had found the Paging class in a previous question.  Apparently when I copied it into Visual Studio, I intermingled two methods, and this somehow caused the issue.  For future reference, I'm posting the relevent methods below.

```
    public int PageCount
    {
        get
        {
            return (this._innerList.Count + this._itemsPerPage - 1) / this._itemsPerPage;
        }
    }

    public int EndIndex
    {
        get
        {
            int end = this._currentPage * this._itemsPerPage - 1;
            return (end > this._innerList.Count) ? this._innerList.Count : end;
        }
    }
```

I had placed the content of the `EndIndex` method inside of the `PageCount` method, and left the `EndIndex` method out entirely.