# WPF ScrollViewer Changed Event fired automatically

Tags: c#, wpf

As per requirement need in C# WPF application , We want to load Data on scrollViewer while moving Horizontal scroll bar.

As we have tried by scrollViewer_ScrollChanged event. But It fired automatically every time while loading of scrollViewer.

In our case we have one grid control inside scrollViewer.

Please help me, looking for positive reply.

Comment: You might just need a boolean flag to keep track of when you're loading data and inside the event handler check that to decide if you'll execute the rest of the event handler or not.

Comment: You mean a [Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid)?