# Discover schema of data source

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, pagination

Which interface(s) does a class need to implement for `DataGrid` to automatically discover its schema and generate columns?

### Details

I'm trying to implement paging for `DataGrid`. The underlying data source is a `DataTable`. Binding `DataGrid` directly to the `DataTable` works fine and `AutoGenerateColumns` does its job.

Due to large size of incoming data and slow `DataGrid` response, I had to use row virtualization, which resulted in several (known) issues and I had to turn it off.

I'm now working on paging approach instead. Found a good implementation of [PagingCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid?noredirect=1&lq=1) and tried it. `DataGrid` correctly generates **rows** for the current page, but **not columns**. Looks like it is not able to read the schema of the underlying collection. (Note that the code at the link does not use `AutoGenerateColumns` and therefore does not suffer from the problem at hand).

I investigated further to see what special interfaces do `DataTable` and `DataView` implement to expose their schema. It appears (and I could be wrong) that `ITypedList` is the interface that I need to implement. I went on to implement this and am now stuck `GetItemProperties()`. There doesn't appear a way to construct `PropertyDescriptor`s manually for each column of the `DataTable`. There is `TypeDesriptor` that can get all public properties of a given type, but that is obviously not going to work for `DataTable` columns.

So, what do I need to do to make my CollectionView class schema become discoverable for the `DataGrid`?

### MCVE

Here is the minimum code that shows the problem with DataGrid:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Select All" Click="SelectAll_Click" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button Content="Deselect All" Click="Deselect_Click" Grid.Row="1" />

    <DataGrid x:Name="DG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Grid.Row="2">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>

      <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode  =TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
      </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code**

```
using System.Data;

class MainWindow
{
  DataTable DT = new DataTable();

  MainWindow()
  {
    // This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent();

    DT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int32)));
    DT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    DT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsSelected", typeof(bool)));

    for (index = 1; index <= 10000; index++) {
      var NR = DT.NewRow();
      NR["ID"] = index;
      NR["Name"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      DT.Rows.Add(NR);
    }

    DG.ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView;
  }

  private void SelectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++) {
      DT.Rows[i]["IsSelected"] = true;
    }
  }

  private void Deselect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++) {
      DT.Rows[i]["IsSelected"] = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Run the code and click **Select All** button. All the rows **appear to be selected**. Scroll down to the bottom of the DataGrid. Click **Deselect All**. Now scroll up slowly. You'll see that many of the rows are still selected. Go to your XAML and disable row virtualization for DataGrid. Selection will now work fine but it will take more time for the DataGrid to load.

Comment: I would say it should be less work to fix DataGrid known issues (what are they? I don't know), than re-implement DataTable +DataView

Comment: What about you write a behavior and based on DataColumn type and Name, add the columns into DataGrid via behaviour?

Comment: @ASh: `DataGrid`, when virtualizing, recycles and reuses containers as we scroll up or down, which makes row/cell selection go haywire.

Comment: @dotNET, try bind row IsSelected to DataTable cell. then selection will update on scroll

Comment: @ASh: Yes, that is what I'm doing. And that is what starts misbehaving when row-virtualization is turned on.

Comment: Have you also enabled `ColumnVirtualization` along with `RowVirtualization`?

Comment: @user1672994: No.

Comment: @dotNET, *that* is more specific question which with an MCVE can be answered in SO format. did you try change VirtualizationMode (Recycling/Standard)?

Comment: @ASh: Hold on. I'm trying to create an MCVE.

Comment: @ASh: An MCVE is now available.

Comment: If you disable the `RowVirtualization` then application creates control for all the rows while rendering that's why load time would be quite higher. So I suggest Not to disable `RowVirtualization` so that existing container can be used on controls which would be rendered on scrolling.

Comment: @user1672994: Thanks for the input, however that is exactly what is causing the problem. Read Details section and check MCVE to see the problem caused by row virtualization.