# How to bring a cell into view

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

Does `ListView` provide a way to bring a specific **cell** into view?

My `ListView` uses a `GridView` and displays several columns, the total width of which is more than the width of `ListView` and therefore requires horizontal scrolling. I'm implementing simple text search and need to bring found cells into view. I can use `ListView.ScrollIntoView()` to get to the target row (vertical scrolling), but am struggling with horizontal scrolling in case target cell is towards left or right of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be using a `DataGrid`? A `DataGrid` supports the functionality you want easily, `ScrollIntoView` has an overload that takes a column and scrolls it into view.

```
private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    grid.ScrollIntoView(vM.Clara, grid.Columns[2]);
}
```

[Gif-Showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a11JB.gif) of setup.

Comment: No. I can't. I was using `DataGrid` and had to move back to `GridView` due to performance problems and a [severe bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405242/discover-schema-of-data-source).